# Use HockeyCoach to trace Crashes

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, crash-reports

I have an app with HockeyApp integrated for crash reporting. I have installed their app named Hockey Coach on my Mac. Whenever my app receives a crash it show it. When double click on a crash it asks for local .git repository of the project. The .Git folder was hidden, I used the terminal command to show it. Now it's showing in finder but in HockeyCoack its not showing. I tried to set .Git folder to unhidden by this terminal command 
      " chflags nohidden /path/ "

But its not working.
How can I use this .Git repo to understand where the crash is happening in the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to select the `.git` folder but the root folder of the repository which contains all the files and the .git folder.

So if you have `~/SourceCode/MyProject/.git` then you select `~/SourceCode/MyProject/`. As you do in any other git GUI app.